# gitlab ci e2e test against nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run e2e tests against a docker image, which is based on the offical nginx image, and built in a step before.

My idea was to make it available via `service` in this way:

```
e2e:
  stage: e2e
  image: weboaks/node-karma-protractor-chrome:alpine
  services:
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      alias: app
  before_script:
    - yarn
    - yarn run webdriver:update --standalone
  script:
    - yarn run e2e:ci
```

The docker file of the as service linked image looks like

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/* && apk add --no-cache -vvv bash
ADD deploy/nginx/conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d
ADD dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But it seems that app isn't available under `http://app`.

Do I miss something or is there any other approach to test against an already created image?

When I run the image with `docker run -p 80:80 local-test` locally or deploy it to a server everything works as expected.